# IMO Shortlist $2009$ - Problem C$1$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Consider $2009$ cards, each having one gold side and one black side, lying on parallel on a long table. Initially all cards show their gold sides. Two player, standing by the same long side of the table, play a game with alternating moves. Each move consists of choosing a block of $50$ consecutive cards, the leftmost of which is showing gold, and turning them all over, so those which showed gold now show black and vice versa. The last player who can make a legal move wins.
> (a) Does the game necessarily end?
> (b) Does there exist a winning strategy for the starting player?

Sol - a) Take the standard binary interpretation with gold=$1$ and black=$0$. Note that the total must decrease with each step, and thus must terminate.

b) No. In fact, the starting player loses no matter what moves are made. To see this, let $a_i=1$ if the $i$th card from the left is gold, and $0$ otherwise, and let $S = a_1+a_{51}+\dots+a_{2001}$, and **remark that the game can only terminate if $S=0$**. But on each move, $S$ changes by $1$, so during the second player's turn, $S$ will always be odd and thus never $0$.

Why game can only terminate if $S=0$ ?

If $2001$th card is $1$ and all previous are $0$'s, game can still end ?

thankyou

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  As I understand it, it is not true that the number of gold cards decreases each round.  Say your first move is to turn cards $2-51$ and that your second move is then to turn cards $1-50$.  The number of gold cards increases between the first and second moves, no?

Comment: To show that the game must terminate, I suggest working inductively.  Clear if there are $50$ cards (whatever the initial pattern)  But if you know the result for $N$ then with $N+1$ argue that you must eventually turn over the left most card, getting you down to the $N$ card game.

Comment: @lulu we are taking consideration not the no. of gold cards,but the total magnitude the no. is making .(that is number made by 0 and 1 )

Comment: Ah, you mean the binary integer made by the $1's$ and $0's$?  Got it.  Yes, that works (and it's easier than my induction).

Comment: As to the second part, I think the collection they consider is off.  I'd look at $\{a_{10}, a_{60}, \cdots, a_{1960}\}$.  There are $40$ of those.

Comment: I don’t think the game can end only if $S=0$. For instance, the first player could turn cards 1-50, the second, 51-100 and so on till we reach the stage where the only non-zero term in $S$ is $a_{2001}$, and the game still ends. But notice at that point it would still be player 2’s turn.

Comment: @Tavish yes,right

Comment: what about {50,100,...,2000} ?

Comment: Sure.  All you need is a collection of evenly many terms such that exactly one must be chosen in any valid move.

Comment: @lulu i still did not get why {50,100,...2000} will be valid,how we can say for sure that each one has to be 0 ?

Comment: @Tavish no,if you select 1-50 then 51-100,...last one will be 1951-2000 .,but i need some rigourus way to prove this works.

Comment: @Ishan Right, my bad.

Comment: I got that @lulu set will work.

Comment: To see that $\{50, 100, \cdots, 2000\}$ works, just consider the possible starting points.  If you happen to choose one of those, then it is clearly ok.  If not, then you chose $i$ with $50n<i<50(n+1)$ for $n\in\{0, \cdots, 39\}$.  Whichever you chose in that region, you will be turning $a_{50(n+1)}$.

Comment: @lulu found another explanation why  {50,100,...2000) work,just think from right ! ,

Comment: @lulu please help me here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956983/usamo-2008-4-triangulation-of-regular-n-gon/3957028#3957028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution is incorrect, for the reason you mentioned; if $a_{2001}=1$ and all other cards are zero, then $S=1$, yet the game is over. The correct solution is to let $T=a_{1960}+a_{1910}+a_{1860}+\dots+a_{10}$, and apply the same logic to $T$. Indeed, if $T>0$, then any nonzero term of $T$ gives a legal move.

They made two mistakes. First of all, they confused left and right, and meant to say that $a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ card from the *right* end. Second, they seemed to be thinking that the rules were as follows: you can select *any* card which is gold, and then flip it and the $49$ cards to its right to the other side. If there are fewer then $49$ such cards, then you just flip all that you can. With these two changes, their value of $S$ works.